# The 36-digit patch in the output of print('%.70f' % (0.2 + 0.1))

Tags: python, floating-point, ieee-754

I understand why `0.1 + 0.2` yields this in Python 3:

```
>>> 0.1 + 0.2
0.30000000000000004
```

...but I don't understand why there is a 36-digit stretch of (mostly) non-zero digits in the middle of the output shown below:

```
>>> print('%.70f' % (0.2 + 0.1))
0.3000000000000000444089209850062616169452667236328125000000000000000000
```

I do expect there to be an difference between 0.1 + 0.2 and the binary IEEE 754 float nearest to 0.1 + 0.2, but I don't understand why this difference would result in a 36-digit representation (corresponding to roughly ~120 bits of precision).

I could understand if the error had a much smaller (< 53 bit) precision, or had an (apparent) infinite precision, maybe be due to an artifact of the algorithm for evaluating `'%.70f' % (0.2 + 0.1)`.  But I can't make sense of an error that would result in the 36-digit patch shown above.

Comment: Roughly speaking, it takes as many decimal digits to output an exact value as there are bits in the floating point. Sure enough, there are 52 significant digits in that number.

Comment: @MarkRansom: that's an interesting rule of thumb.  Does it hold for other bases besides 10?

Comment: It works for any base that is a multiple of 2. Base 10 is 2*5 so it works, base 6 would too because it's 2*3.  Base 7 wouldn't but base 14 would.

Comment: @MarkRansom: That's amazing.  I just tested it with a few different even bases.  Based on these tests, I would refine the rule slightly to "*at most* as many digits in the representation as there are bits in the floating point".  Still, I'm mystified by the rule.  Why does it work?  Maybe this should be a separate SO question...

Comment: This is most likely an interesting read: https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2012/03/08/float-precisionfrom-zero-to-100-digits-2/

Comment: @kjo - Ponder multiplying the binary by 2^53 and the decimal by 10^53.  Then ponder that 2^53 is a factor of 10^53.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Python implementation you are using apparently uses IEEE-754 binary64 for floating-point. (This is common, but Python does not mandate it.)

In this format, numbers are represented as multiples of powers of two, where the specific power of two used depends on the magnitude of the number. (The floating-point format is also described in other ways that are mathematically equivalent to this, such as using a significand with a fixed number of fractional bits instead of an integer multiple as I am using here. This description is easier for the explanation at hand.)

For numbers around .3, the power of two used is 2<sup>−54</sup>. The result of adding `.1` and `.2`, after rounding to fit in the floating-point format is 5404319552844596 times 2<sup>−54</sup>, or 5404319552844596 / 2<sup>54</sup>.

That number, 5404319552844596 / 2<sup>54</sup>, is exactly 0.3000000000000000444089209850062616169452667236328125.

Comment: @kjo: Right you are. I copied and pasted the wrong thing from some work I did.